# How to resolve javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path for basic Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, pom.xml

Im new to Spring Boot and was trying to implement basic Spring Security for a single endpoint in my Spring Boot controller. But I dont know how to resolve the Circular View Error

My Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class HelloSecurityController {
    
    @RequestMapping({"/hello"})
    public static String helloWorld() {
        return "hello";
    }
```

My Security Configurer Class

````
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);

    
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
    ```
````

My MyUserDetailsService  which returns a simple User with Password

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        return new User("foo","foo", new ArrayList<>());
```

The Dependencies I kept in maven pom file during initializing Spring Boot Project

```
<dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The Package structure of my project:
[proj_struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THV2a.png)

After logging in using the username and password at the login form page generated by spring security Im getting the error:
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [hello]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/api/hello] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

I have not kept any static template (HTML/JSP) in the templates folder. I dont know if I have to as after login I just want to see a simple String. How do I resolve this?

Comment: If you want to see a simple string use `@RestController` not `@Controller`.

Comment: Thanks !!. It works. However. If I indeed want to keep the controller annotation as @Controller and wish to return a view name and wish to render a view in the form of Html page like in Spring MVC will just keeping a html page in the templates folder with the same view name work? Or another endpoint needs to be added as well in the controller?

Comment: That should do the trick.